# How to link the otherButtonTitles in UIAlertView to initiate the Tweeter composer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uialertview, tweets

is it possible (if yes how) to be able to send a tweet by pressing OtherButtonTitles button in a UIAlertView?

My code does a calculation upon a button press in "IBAction" and returns the result in a string as the "message" in "UIAlertView". i would like to add a second button, in "OtherButtonTitles", which when click will bring up the native tweeting page. but i dunno how to link the button to send a tweet.

```
    else{

    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You require an average GPA of at least %.2f to achieve your Goal of %@", gpagoal, (NSString *)[myPickerDelegate.myGoal objectAtIndex: [myPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]]]; 

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Nothing is Impossible" 
                                                    message:str 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Good Luck" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Tweet",nil];

    //show alert
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    NSLog(@"All Valid");
}
```

should it be something like

```
otherButtonTitles:@"Tweet", [self sendEasyTweet:(something here, dunno what to add)]];
```

"- (IBAction)sendEasyTweet:(id)sender" is a method i made to call up the tweeter composer with a standalone button. but due to the design of the app, i would like the tweeter button to be shown with the UIAlertView and not as a standalone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, but you cannot set it directly. You have to implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate` and catch the method that gets executed when a button is pressed.

[UIAlertViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) (look for `– alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`)

Comment: Thanks for your response. so i add in  a new method call 
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)1{
and call my sendEasyTweet?
}

Comment: Wouldn't place that 1 there, but yeah, that's the idea.

Comment: ooh so if my button is at index 1, what should i type? 
if i have a few different alert view all trying to call a tweeter composer but with different tweet template for the respective alert view, do i create different sendEasyTweet template? btw how do i call my sendEasyTweet method in the alertView method?

Comment: I'm guessing you're new to software development? You'll want to check whether the number passed is 1. If that's true, call it. Of course, you'll still have to pass the strings to the "tweeter", but I'd rather leave that up to you. I suggest reading a good programming book.

Comment: okay thanks tom for answering my question. yea i am new to objective-c trying to learn from everyone here =)